# Look through the function workspace in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, workspace

Let's imagine that you are dividing your script by parts using functions. Every one has its own workspace. Is there any way to switch between workspaces and directly have a look at its content? It's just like we do with the base workspace.

Comment: Functions have their own workspaces?

Comment: Yes, they have. I rely on the official MathWorks documentation. These different workspace types are used to protect data access.

Comment: Ah I think I know what you mean now. The question is very unclear and just saying you `rely on the official MathWorks documentation` doesn't really help either.

Comment: Ok, sorry for my English :) I just wonder how to view function variables' values to check them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to **inspect** different (read: *parent*) workspaces, you can do that **while debugging** using the "Function Call Stack" menu as shown below:

[image: Callstack selection during debug]

Each of the displayed lines (in this example: `updateSourceImageAndStats`, `loadCallback`, `Base`) represents a different workspace, and switching between them will show you the contents of the workspace for that level. Also consider [`dbstack`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstack.html) and related functions.

If however you want to **execute** code in some parent workspace, you can use [`evalin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/evalin.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help! "Step In", "Step Out" and Breakpoints allow to monitor everything in functions and out of them.